# angular: best way to provide local storage data? Set rootScope in each controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

In an Angular app, I want to keep a couple of variables "global". I chose localStorage as a persister for this. Advantage: on page refresh, the global "state" of the app is retained.

The service providing such a local storage

My question: what is the cleanest method to provide this locally stored data to every controller and further to the view? Do I have to remember to:

- inject my local storage into every controller
- in each controller, assign the local storage data to the controller's scope?

Further info:

For example: On login, I select the project ("On which project are you going to work today?"). this project should be a global variable.

The app is constructed in a way that the header section is served by controller A and the content area is served by controller B.

I then would have to inject the local storage data into controller A and B.

```
angular.module('app').controller('ControllerA', function ($scope, Session) ...y
```

And in both Controllers, I would have to provide the data to the corresponding view by:

```
$scope.session = $localStore.getData();
```

I do not like the fact that I have to think about these lines for each controller. Is this a clean and preferred way to have such global app data?

Remark: no need to have a dynamic binding. On the landing page, the user selects the project  which is then persisted and can be retrieved read-only by all subsequent controllers. If the global variables would need to be dynamic, things would be different.

**JSFiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Wr7LS/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to put localStorage in angular-service wrapper and inject it in places where you need to use this data.

no need for rootScope.

Comment: I ended up doing like you said. I used ngStorage for this purpose (wrapper for localStorage) and inject it where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to use shared values between controllers is the [RootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) variable. Every controller see it same values.

Comment: Yeah but rootScope does not survive a page refresh. I'm afraid it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Hmm:) On that situation the answer will be the local storage. If u not similar with this, read this [tutorial](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). After that you can see this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576246/A-Shopping-Cart-Application-Built-with-AngularJS) in Angular JS shopping cart implementation use local storage ( session storage ).